# TCP connection between two openshift containers

Tags: tcp, openshift

I have two applications (diy container type) which have to be connected via TCP. Let's take as example application `clusternode1` and `clusternode2`.

Each one has TCP listener set up for `$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP:$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT`.

For some reason `clusternode1` fails to connect to any of the following options for `clusternode2`:

- `$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP:$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT`
- `$OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS`

Can you please help in understanding what should be url for external TCP connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check the logs to see if the OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP for both apps are within the same subnet.  If one, say, is...

1.2.3.4

...and the other is...

1.5.6.7

...for example, then you might not expect Amazon's firewalls to just arbitrarily allow TCP traffic from one subnet to another.  If this were allowed by default then one person's app might try to hack another's.

I know that when you're dealing directly with Amazon AWS and you spin up multiple virtual servers you have to create virtual zones to allow traffic between them.  This might be something that's necessary.

[Proxy Ports](http://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_system_architecture_guide.html#proxy-ports) I don't know if this is useful but it's possible that a private IP address is being bound to your application(s) and then a NAT server is translating that into a public IP address.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will have a look at the url you posted.

Comment: On another hand I thought that this simple requirement which comes up very often in distributed systems deployment should be something by default I cloud services. Probably I ask for too much :(

Comment: You'd probably appreciate this more if you had a direct Amazon AWS account and could play with it there.  It's pretty cool, btw.  And yet I found it a bit overwhelming in the amount of work necessarily to spin up two servers (web + SQL), to bind them together into the same virtual zone, etc.  They make it simple to spin up a webserver (alone) so that it can talk to the Internet, proper.  To create two spin-up server instances that are allowed to talk to each other?  It's more complicated.

Comment: i will probably go to digitalocean as they claim to have this feature (private networking) out of the box for the instances within one data center.